# How to read 3d array of integers from file and store it in 1d array

Tags: arrays, c, parsing, image-processing, text-processing

I have 3d array stored in .txt file that looks like this (720x1280 with image pixels locations stored in python, 1st number is x, second is y)(shorten):

```
[[[ 253  122]
  [ 253  121]
  [ 253  121]
  ...
  [1027  119]
  [1027  120]
  [1028  120]]

 [[ 252  122]
  [ 253  122]
  [ 253  122]
  ...
  
  [1067  573]
  [1067  573]
  [1067  573]]]
```

**First:** So now I have to read this file and store this integers in 1d array.
**Second:** Use it on input image to remap it. Input image is represented with 1d array with 720x1280 elements.
This is example of rotating input image. I have to do remap with loaded pixels locations from file.

```
for(rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < height; rowIdx++)
    {
        for(colIdx = 0; colIdx < width; colIdx++)
        {
            temp = inputPtr[rowIdx * width + colIdx];
            inputPtr[rowIdx * width + colIdx] = inputPtr[height * width - rowIdx * width - colIdx];
            inputPtr[height * width - rowIdx * width - colIdx] = temp;
        }
    }
```

**Solved**, allocated array for 12843200 elements, took x,y and got exact location and saved it to array file:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(void)
{
  int *array;
  array = (int*)malloc(1843200 * sizeof(int));
  int i = 0;
  FILE *file;
  FILE *f = fopen("array.txt", "w+");

  if (file = fopen("file1.txt", "r"))
  {
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &array[i]) != EOF)
    {
      i++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    array[i] = '\0';

    
     //for (i = 0; i < 30;i++){
    for (i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++){
     if(i % 2 != 0){
     
          printf("%d, ", array[i] * 1280 + array[i-1]);
          fprintf(f,"%d, ",array[i] * 1280 + array[i-1]);
          }
    }
  }
  
 fclose(f);
    free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

and also removed brackets from input file so it only separated with spaces.

Comment: Your text does not have an actual question in it. Your title does not fit the text (2d in the title, 3d in the text). What is your problem? Reading it as a 1D array? Read one number after another and ignore the square brackets.

Comment: Fixing the title of your question is not sufficient. Explain what specifically you are having problems with. Show your (unfinished/non-working) code as a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am not an C expert so first I need help to open file, go trough all elements, ignore the square brackets and spaces and just store all these numbers to simple 1d array, as it will be array with 1,843,200 elements..

Comment: And the best option for me will maybe be to store first element in one array, and second to another array. For example, 253 in first array, 122 in second, 253 in first, 121 in second and so on, because first one represents x coordinates and second one y

Comment: It seems that you are keeping a `'\0'` terminated array of `Uint32`s (I assume those are `uint32_t`s). Good practice aside, keep in mind this only works if you can guarantee that the value of `0` is never read from your input file into the array (as `0 == '\0'`). Also note that if you are reading in exactly 1843200 values writing the `'\0'` terminator invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: **focus** on one thing at a time, i.e. first parsing that text file, _then_ the other stuff. -- why do you make your life hard by having to parse that text file? you can tell numpy to dump the data in a binary format. that's a lot easier to handle. -- [tour], [ask] -- inplace array operations are going to fail. assign newly calculated values into a new array. learn how remapping works ("pull", for each output pixel, calculate source coordinate and sample input there)

Comment: OT: `(int*)malloc(...` the `(int*)` cast is useless, just write `(malloc(...`.

Comment: **do not** put the answer in the question. post an answer.